# Visual Studio 2010 Randomly Stops Building

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, msbuild, compiler-errors

I am having a problem with Visual Studio 2010 as of late that I can't figure out. Lately after having VS2010 open for an extended period of time, building begins to fail without error. This includes build, rebuild, and clean.

The output from VS2010 is only two lines:

```
When trying build:

    1>------ Build started: Project: example, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
    ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

When trying rebuild:

    1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: example, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
    ========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========

When trying clean:

    1>------ Clean started: Project: example, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
    ========== Clean: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

The only way I can resume using VS to build the project(s) is to restart my system. However, using msbuild from the commandline builds the project(s) without issue. So this appears to be related to VS itself but I can't figure out whats causing it with no actual error being displayed.

I have tried restarting VS itself, deleting .suo, .ncb, precompiled headers, etc. to see if it is a file lock issue which did not help or fix the problem. There are no stray processes running from a previous build when this starts happening either.

Edit --8<------------------------------------------

Just for some added information:

- I have reinstalled VS2010 twice to try to correct this.
- I have reinstalled VS2010 SP1 twice along with that.
- This only happens with VS after an extended period of time.
- It seems to occur when modifying a header (C++) file for a long time.
- After it happens I can still build from the command line fine just not from VS until I restart the system.

Comment: Tools + Options, Projects and Solutions, Build and Run.  Bump up the "MSBuild project build output verbosity" setting.

Comment: @HansPassant: Thanks for your reply, I have set the verbosity of Visual Studio to max and it still only reports the above statements. :( (I also added some more info to the main post.)

Comment: Right, you have to dig through the diagnostics and figure out what failed.  Post it somewhere if you can't figure it out.

Comment: @HansPassant : I've looked at the log file since the output window does not change, however the log file is empty when this starts happening. If I delete all debug/release folders and rebuild as debug mode, the only file created is debug/project_name.log which is empty and the build fails.

Comment: Hmm, you edited your comment, could have sworn that you reported seeing diagnostic output before.  Vexing problem, environmental no doubt.  Sucks when your machine goes bad like that.  Never seen this reported before either.  You could arbitrarily kill off processes or go back in time with a restore point.  More of a superuser.com kinda question, really.

Comment: May sound like a stupid question, but do you have a virus scanner running? Can you turn it off and try again? But we're getting into longshot territory now, so as Hans Passant says, it might be more of a Super User issue.

Comment: @HansPassant - Thanks for your input. I didn't remove anything when I made edits, only added. No extra info is displayed after changing the verbosity settings sadly.

It does seem to correct itself if I let VS sit untouched for about 10 minutes, leading me to believe something is getting stuck / locked and preventing the build from starting.

Comment: @Bart - My system does not have any anti-virus installed. I do not use it to do anything aside from personal work. The system is kept up to date as well so I do not think it is anything virus related given the behavoir of this issue.

Comment: @atom0s Hmm, okay. I was not hinting at a virus, but more at the virus scanner taking hold of any of the files needed during compilation. I have had an issue like that, although admittedly many years ago.

Comment: @Bart - No worries, any help towards resolving this issue is appreciated. I've reposted this on SuperUser.com as you both directed as well hopefully someone can figure out whats causing this to happen. :(

Comment: Fixed your title. `Visual Studio 2010 Stops Building Randomly` is a very good thing

Comment: @atom0s Did you find the solution?

Comment: I reformatted since I could not find a real solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit late to respond to this but I never did figure out what caused this issue to happen. I landed up reformatting shortly after I posted this question. Thanks all who tried to help though.

Answer (score 0):

If it started suddenly, keeps happening, and happens on different projects, try testing your RAM.  You can download an ISO for memtest86, burn, and boot to it.

Comment: I've since landed up reformatting due to the issue and then in turn got a new laptop. Thanks all whom tried to help. So this is no longer an issue. Not sure if I have to mark this closed manually or not. But figured it would be nice to keep those whom tried informed.

Comment: I can add that VS2010 is officially full of UI bugs. Just check the amount of absolutely bogus issues that have been reported at connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback. EDIT: Silently hoping that VS2012 solves any of that.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but try rebuilding and cleaning solution if this happens to you again. It helped me.